# Google maps with d3.js (v5) overlay

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, d3.js

I'm working on a project where I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
 [
    {
        "lat": 53.1521596106757,
        "lon": -0.486577431632087,
        "size": 3598,
        "field": "TestField",
        "variety": "TestVariety",
        "count": 67
    },
    {
        "lat": 53.1521596106757,
        "lon": -0.486287281632087,
        "size": 4077,
        "field": "TestField",
        "variety": "TestVariety",
        "count": 73
    }
]
```

I'm trying to add text using count but I'm not seeing the results I expect using the following code:

```
let testField = new google.maps.LatLng(53.1519, -0.4895);

const map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select('#map').node(), {
  zoom: 17,
  center: testField,
  mapTypeId: 'satellite',
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
});

//colour scale
// const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues);    

d3.json('/small_example.json')
  .then(data => {

    let countInfo = data.map(function (testVariety) {
      return testVariety.count;
    })

    // colorScale.domain(data.map(d => d.countInfo))

    //create overlay
    const overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
    overlay.onAdd = function () {
      const layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append('div')
        .attr('class', 'panes');

      // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
      overlay.draw = function () {
        const projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;

        const marker = layer.selectAll('svg')
          .data(d3.entries(data))
          .each(transform) // update existing markers
          .enter().append('svg')
          .each(transform)
          .attr('class', 'marker')

        //add a rect
        marker.append('rect')
          .attr('height', 15)
          .attr('width', 15)
        // .style('fill', d => colorScale(d.count));
        // .style('fill', function(d) {return d.count})

        let countInfo = data.map(function (testVariety) {
          return testVariety.count;
        })

        countInfo.forEach(element => {
          //add lable
          marker.append('text')
            .attr('x', padding + 7)
            .attr('y', padding)
            .attr('dy', '.31em')
            .each(transform)
            .text(function (d) {
              return element
            });
          console.log(element)
        });

        function transform(d) {
          d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value.lat, d.value.lon);
          d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
          return d3.select(this)
            .style('left', (d.x - padding) + 'px')
            .style('top', (d.y - padding) + 'px')
        }
      };
    };

    // Bind overlay to the map
    overlay.setMap(map);
  });
```

console.log(element) is bringing up the results I want to see but I can't figure out how to display it on screen.

I feel I'm getting close but need a hand getting over the line.

Comment: My code is based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to always make your example a snippet where you can, so that it is a minimal reproducible example, including data, library versions, all script tags etc.

But for your example, the external code frame with cross-origin will not work on the stack overflow snippet (at least not consistently for me with Chrome). So, in that case, try to use something like codePen or another code sandbox type site.

My full example is below (but it doesn't run consistently in Stack overflow for me) or it's available (working) at codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/mdVOmJL

The most important thing you missed is this part:

Before:

```js
const marker = layer.selectAll('svg')
          .data(d3.entries(data)) //tansform object to array
          .each(transform) // update existing markers
          .enter().append('svg')
          .each(transform)
          .attr('class', 'marker')
```

after:

```js
const marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
          .data(data) //no need to transform array of objects
          .each(transform) // update existing markers
          .enter().append("svg")
          .each(transform)
          .attr("class", "marker");
```

Take a look at the example code you referenced again: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711

Their data is of the following form. Meaning it is an object with each key as the 4 letter code and then the corresponding value is an array of form `[lat, lon, longName, someArr]`:

```js
{
  "KMAE":[-120.12,36.98,"MADERA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT",[26,1,2,5,6,3,2,1,2,7,29,12,3]],
  "KSJC":[-121.92,37.37,"SAN JOSE INTERNATIONAL  AIRPORT",[28,1,1,1,6,10,5,3,2,4,14,21,7]],
  ...
}
```

Whereas your data is of the following form. Meaning it is an array of objects, each with keys for lat, lon, field etc. and the corresponding values assigned to each of those properties, on each object:

```js
[
    {
        "lat": 53.1521596106757,
        "lon": -0.486577431632087,
        "size": 3598,
        "field": "TestField",
        "variety": "TestVariety",
        "count": 67
    },
    {
        "lat": 53.1521596106757,
        "lon": -0.486287281632087,
        "size": 4077,
        "field": "TestField",
        "variety": "TestVariety",
        "count": 73
    },
    ...
];
```

So, while the example you referenced's data needed to be converted with `d3.entries(data)`, your data was already an array, so you didn't need to convert it from an object to an array, you can just apply the data directly.

```js
// Create the Google Map…
const map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5, -0.466),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

// Load the field data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
//this is commented our for example purposes, and data is declared directly above
//d3.json("/small_example.json", function(error, data) {
  //if (error) throw error;

  const overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    const layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {
      const projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 10;

      const marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
          .data(data)
          .each(transform) // update existing markers
        .enter().append("svg")
          .each(transform)
          .attr("class", "marker");

      // Add a circle.
      marker.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .attr("cx", padding)
          .attr("cy", padding);

      // Add a label.
      marker.append("text")
          .attr("x", padding + 7)
          .attr("y", padding)
          .attr("dy", ".31em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.field; });

      function transform(d) {
        d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.lon);
        d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
        return d3.select(this)
            .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
            .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
      }
    };
  };

  // Bind our overlay to the map…
  overlay.setMap(map);
//this closing bracket pair is commented out, while d3.json() is not in use: 
//});
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.stations, .stations svg {
  position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.stations circle {
  fill: brown;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<script id="initData">
const data = [
    {
  "lat": 53.1521596106757,
  "lon": -0.486577431632087,
  "size": 3598,
  "field": "TestField",
  "variety": "TestVariety",
  "count": 67
 },
 {
  "lat": 53.1521596106757,
  "lon": -0.486287281632087,
  "size": 4077,
  "field": "TestField",
  "variety": "TestVariety",
  "count": 73
 }
];
</script>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!